# jQuery load() on large files within a loop leaves browser unresponsive. How to fix?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a loop around the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#" + divname[k]).load(documentname[k] + ".html", function(a, b) {
        console.log(documentname[k] + " was loaded");
    });
});
```

the loop is about 30-50 iterations, each file is different and weighs about 1mb.

I have tried on safari and chrome, both browsers become unresponsive for a good 1-2min until everything is loaded and control is given back to the user.

If the loop is only 10 items long, it works fine without freezing.
I did a lot of research and it seems that $().load should work asynchronously without freezing the UI. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Use Ajax instead after loading all others (css, html and JS file)

Answer (score -1):

If you have this placed at the top of your page, and that page has other `HTML` elements to it which don't need to be loaded in, consider placing the JavaScript at the bottom of the page, so it is the last thing to be loaded.

You could also place that code in a [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.